# How to calculate sum of amount for current month including the amount of previous months in Power Bi?

Tags: sum, powerbi

I would like to create  DAX expression. This is the condition and I have my month and year table in separate column.

If we choose Month as a March then it should show the sum of amount of Jan, Feb and as well as March. Similarly, If we choose Month as Dec then it should have the sum from Jan to Dec.

How can we write DAX expression for this condition in Power Bi?

Comment: Do you have separate Calendar/Date table?

Comment: Nope I don't have separate date table but I do have date column in the same data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a measure as below. You need to have a separate Date/Calendar table for that which is connected to your Data table using Date column.

```
total_amount_ytd = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[your_amount_column_name]),
    DATESYTD(your_date_table_name[your_date_column_name])
)
```

With this above **Measure**, if you add Year/Month in a table with the new Measure, you will find the value per year will increase from January to December for a single year and starts re calculating from January again in the next year.

Comment: I have one another question. Is this above measure works if we don't have date column in the different table?

Comment: Didn't try this case and thats why can not confirm it now.